# How to use STDOUT in php

Tags: php, command-line

I am running into a project that read a stream from a txt file, so in the CLI, i write:

```
cat texte.txt|php index.php
```

In my `index.php` file i read the stream:

```
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
```

Now i have a `$result` that contains the result of my processing file and i want to output it with `STDOUT`, I looked in the manual, but I don't know how to use it, can you please make me a use example.

Comment: What did you try? Did you even try? `print` and `echo`?

Comment: yes, but my project requirements are to use STDOUT, are print and echo part of the STDOUT stream?

Comment: yes, standard echo and print like @Cicada wrote goes to STDOUT.

Comment: Judging from your first code sample, it looks like you actually want to use STDIN, not STDOUT. Your shell command will pipe `cat`'s output into the `php` process, where it becomes *input* to `php`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Okay, let me give you another example for the [`STDIN`](http://php.net/STDIN) and [`STDOUT`](http://php.net/STDOUT) usage.

In PHP you use these two idioms:

```
 $input = fgets(STDIN);

 fwrite(STDOUT, $output);
```

When from the commandline you utilize them as such:

```
 cat "input.txt"  |  php script.php   >  "output.txt"

 php script.php  < input.txt  > output.txt

 echo "input..."  |  php script.php   |  sort  |  tee  output.txt
```

That's all these things do. Piping in, or piping out. And the incoming parts will appear in `STDIN`, whereas your output should go to `STDOUT`. Never cross the streams, folks!

Comment: Do those two streams of any use in a web application context?

Comment: Not normally. You only use echo/print/STDOUT for sending output to the webserver+client. Everything send through STDERR would end up in the webservers error.log (if configured).

Comment: `$output` can be a string like `fwrite(STDOUT, 'here');`?

Answer (score 34):

The constants `STDIN` and `STDOUT` are already resources, so all you need to do is

```
fwrite(STDOUT, 'foo');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

> php://stdin, php://stdout and php://stderr allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process. The stream references a duplicate file descriptor, so if you open php://stdin and later close it, you close only your copy of the descriptor-the actual stream referenced by STDIN is unaffected. Note that PHP exhibited buggy behavior in this regard until PHP 5.2.1. It is recommended that you simply use the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers.

Comment: `PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in` PHP 5.4 while `$out = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');` works

Comment: `fwrite(STDOUT, "foo");` --> `Undefined constant "STDOUT"`

Answer (score 26):

this should work for you

```
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w'); //output handler
fputs($out, "your output string.\n"); //writing output operation
fclose($out); //closing handler
```

Comment: i do not understand what is wrong with the answer.. i tried and it worked ((: i think bad commentation caused this.

Comment: It *does* work indeed, I am not criticizing that. But those 3 function calls can be replaced with **one** language construct. `echo` or `print`.

Comment: @Cicada keep in mind that echo'ing is a side effect most of the time. A stream is a dependency. If you are writing unit-tests, you will want to use streams in order to mock/stub them in your tests.

Comment: +1 for `php://output` , `php://stdout` did not work for me @Cicada I needed to use fputcsv and had STDOUT undefined

Comment: php://output is the client output, stdout is the standard output of the PHP server.