# Not able to interact with php file in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I downloaded xampp and am running a PHP file in my localhost, however, I cannot receive user input from the program, any idea what I am doing wrong? I used both fscanf and readline, but both just stop the program from running.

Comment: How are you running the PHP file? with an HTTP request through Apache or NGINX or from the command line (CLI)?. To read command line arguments such as `php yourscript.php "My name is James"` then use `$argc` for argument **c**ount and `$argv` as an array of the **v**alues. The first argument is the script filename itself. Then for the input, output and error streams, you can [refer to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) or [to this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782174/653182)

Answer (score 0):

With web programming, how PHP accesses use input depends on the method that was used to send it.

Primarily this is via the superglobals `$_POST` and `$_GET` along with `$_FILES`.

To read request bodies that aren't standard HTML form data types, you would use `file_get_contents('php://input');`. (This is typically used for JSON formatted requests).

Adjacent to user input there are `$_COOKIE` and `$_SERVER`.

---

It sounds like your level of experience with PHP web programming is such that you should be working with introductory material rather than stack overflow. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) recommends [this guide](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_Essentials) which includes [this section on PHP and HTML forms](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_and_HTML_Forms)